# Assigning data in using x-init of alpine are not applied

Tags: alpine.js

With alpine@v2.x.x and axios": "^0.19.2 I try to get data using x-init, as I
read here https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine with the code:

```
<div
    class="todo_list_wrapper"
    x-data="addTodos()"
    x-init="initTodos()"
>
    
    <ul>
        
        <template x-for="nextTodo in todos" :key="nextTodo.id">
            <div class="todo_content_1 row_content">
                <div class="m-2" x-text="nextTodo.title" :class="{ 'todo_completed' : nextTodo.completed } " >
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    
    
    </ul>

</div>

<script>
    function initTodos() {
        console.log('initTodos()::')
        axios.get('/api/todos', {
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log("response::")
            console.log(response)
            this.todos= response.data
            console.log('FROM initTodos() this.todos::')
            console.log(this.todos)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        });

    }

    function addTodos() {
        console.log('addTodos::')
        return {
            todos : [],

            /*
                        todos : [{
                            id:1,
                            title:"Task 1",
                            completed: true
                        },
                            {
                            id:2,
                            title:"Task 2",
                            completed: false
                        }],
            */

        }
    }
```

In the console I see that addTodos with data declaration is run first and initTodos() with data
retrieved from db: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A1gN.jpg
but my listing is empty. If to uncomment 2 lines inside of addTodos() - I see these rows,
but not returned from db.

What is wrong? I expected assigning this.todos must be reactive...